Dependent Visa (Will current employer be notified?)
A friend of mine is going to Germany in few weeks through a work visa. She's planning to take a dependent visa for her husband once she's settled there. She wants to know whether her current company would be notified of the dependent visa request from her. She doesn't want them to know and is willing to raise the visa request by herself.

What country is she currently residing in?

According to Make it in Germany providing proof of secure livelihood is required when applying. Which could mean the authorities will verify the proof with the employer.

@Traveller, But I wonder if data protection laws would allow the authorities to inform the company of the specific reason for their request. I kind of doubt it, but really don't know. It may depend on the country of residence - which I suspect is the UK from the wording.

The employer might still get to know indirectly, for example through the change of tax bracket if they are married and file jointly. Instead of tiptoeing around, it might be better to address why they don't want the employer to know? From an employers perspective, wouldn't it be postitive to know your employee is in it for good and really committed to moving to Germany?
